# Update Macbook to newest supported OSX version?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My Late 2008 Aluminium Macbook has 10.9.5 on it. The update tool offered me Sierra but then predictably told me I can't have it as this Mac is too old. I don't know what the last supported OSX version is for this Mac... is there a way I can get it?

In an ideal world I'd like to do a clean install as this MacBook is full of all kinds of crud I don't want anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest OS supported on a Late 2008 Aluminum MacBook is OS X 10.11.6 and can be downloaded from [this link which will open in the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12).

Note that while is starts off saying "This version of OS X El Capitan is for users running OS X Snow Leopard...", **it also says...*** "This version of El Capitan can also be used on Mac computers that are not compatible with Sierra.".

---

You can use the instructions in [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) to create a USB Installer to do a clean install of OS X El Capitan.

> **Use the 'createinstallmedia' command in Terminal**
>
> 1. Download the macOS installer from the Mac App Store. Quit the installer if it opens automatically after downloading. The installer
>      will be in your Applications folder.
> 2. Mount your USB flash drive or other volume. You could also use a secondary internal partition that has at least 12GB of available disk
>      space for the installation files.
> 3. Open the Terminal app, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
> 4. Use the `createinstallmedia` command in Terminal to create the bootable installer. For detailed usage instructions, make sure that
>      the appropriate macOS installer is in your Applications folder, then
>      enter one of the following paths in Terminal:
>
> Path for El Capitan:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
> ```
>
> **Example**
>
> This is the basic syntax of the command. Replace `volumepath` with the
>   path to your USB flash drive or other volume, and replace
>   `installerpath` with the path to the Install OS X app.
>
> ```
> createinstallmedia --volume volumepath --applicationpath installerpath
> ```
>
> The following examples assume that the OS X installer is in your
>   Applications folder and the name of your USB flash drive or other
>   volume is MyVolume:
>
> Example for El Capitan:
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app
> ```

After creating the USB Installer, you can boot the Mac with it and do a clean install.  Make sure you backup anything you do not want to loose before erasing the HDD and installing OS X El Capitian.